# What is the easiest way to compare the numbers in this function?

Tags: javascript

I have 10 levels and each level has a levelversion. Now I want to compare if a certain level has the same levelversion as declared in the function. For example, I want to find out if levelversion == level3version when level = 3.

For example, if level = 3 and levelversion = 1

```
function CompareLevelVersion(level, levelversion)
{
var downloadlevel = "";
var level1version = 1;
var level2version = 1;
var level3version = 1;
var level4version = 1;
var level5version = 1;
var level6version = 1;
var level7version = 1;
var level8version = 1;
var level9version = 1;
var level10version = 1;
var levelstring = "level" + level + "version";

if (Number(levelversion) == Number(levelstring))
    downloadlevel = false;
else
    downloadlevel = true;

return downloadlevel;
}
```

Normally, this code should return downloadlevel = false because levelversion = 1 and var level3version = 1. But something is not working because it returns downloadlevel = true and I found out that Number(levelstring) = "NaN".

What is wrong? Why is Number(levelstring) = "NaN"?

Comment: Better to create an rather than declaring 10 variables

Comment: An alphabetical letter is not going to be a number, no matter how many times you call `Number()` on it.

Comment: What you're trying to do is the reason arrays exist.

Comment: `levelstring` is NaN (short for `Not a Number`) because it's a word, not a number. You can't convert the word / string ("level<number-here>version") to a number.

Comment: You cannot create a variable name with the concatenation, it will be a string always. In easy way, you are doing, Number("level1version") which is not pointing to a variable

Comment: create an array with 10 elements, level will be the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like: OR create an index based array

```js
function CompareLevelVersion(level, levelversion) {
  var downloadlevel = "";
  var levelVersionObj = {}
  levelVersionObj.level1version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level2version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level3version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level4version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level5version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level6version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level7version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level8version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level9version = 1;
  levelVersionObj.level10version = 1;

  var levelstring = "level" + level + "version";

  if (Number(levelversion) == Number(levelVersionObj[levelstring]))
    downloadlevel = false;
  else
    downloadlevel = true;

  return downloadlevel;
}

console.log(CompareLevelVersion(1, 1))
console.log(CompareLevelVersion(2, 2))
```